# Okta scim user automatic provision of user failed

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, scim, snowflake-connector

I configured okta snowflake SSO. I assigned users as well. I configures scim which has permission to create users, deactivate users, sync password. After i configure scim i am having errors for existing users Automatic provisioning of user to app snowflake failed. Error while creating user. Conflict. Error reported by remote server. User exist with given user name. Same thing happening when I am assigning the app to existing user with same user name. Is there any way to fix it or is it best to remove scim.

Comment: I can't recall if you can run import from SF first and do match to existing users in Okta. That can help

Comment: I tried with import as well but after I configure scim it's still the same error

Answer (score 0):

In order for the merge to be successful, the login mapping needs to be exactly the same (the rest gets updated by okta). So make sure users can login via SSO first.

[image: Snowflake Okta mappings]

You also need to transfer ownership manually. Documentation provides this command:

```
use role accountadmin;
grant ownership on user <user_name> to role okta_provisioner;
```

[Snowflake SCIM doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-okta.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the issue please check the following:

- Fetch the Mapping which you have on the SCIM provisioning app.
- Check that the user which is getting synched with the attributes as derived from the above step.
- If the user exists please check the owner of the user.
- If the owner is other than the provisioned role AAD_PROVISIONER, OKTA_PROVISIONER then change the ownership of the user to the above role.

Try to sync again, you should not get into this error.